# NPOI font of CellStyle doesn't work and sheet has to be repaired

Tags: c#, .net-core, npoi

I'm trying to style link in Excel, but for some reason I cannot get `CellStyle Font` to work

**.NET Core 2.1**

**NPOI: 2.1.4**

Error:

> Excel completed file-level validation and repair. Some parts of this workbook may have been repaired or rejected.
>   Records repaired: Font from parts /xl/styles.xml (Styles)

This works fine:

```
var myStyle = workbook.CreateCellStyle();

myStyle.BorderBottom = BorderStyle.Double;

cell.Hyperlink = new XSSFHyperlink(HyperlinkType.Url) { Address = url };
cell.CellStyle = myStyle;
```

This does not:

```
var myStyle = workbook.CreateCellStyle();
var myFont = workbook.CreateFont();

myStyle.BorderBottom = BorderStyle.Double;

myStyle.SetFont(myFont);
cell.Hyperlink = new XSSFHyperlink(HyperlinkType.Url) { Address = url };
cell.CellStyle = myStyle;
```

This does not2:

```
var myStyle = workbook.CreateCellStyle();
var myFont = workbook.CreateFont();

myStyle.BorderBottom = BorderStyle.Double;
myFont.Color = IndexedColors.Blue.Index;

myStyle.SetFont(myFont);
cell.Hyperlink = new XSSFHyperlink(HyperlinkType.Url) { Address = url };
cell.CellStyle = myStyle;
```

I tried setting `myFont.Color` using

- IndexedColors.Blue.Index;
- HSSFColor.Blue.Index;
- HSSFColor.Blue.Index2;
- new XSSFColor(Color.Blue).Indexed;

and everytime result is the same - Excel is repairing sheet.

Any idea?

edit

> if you remove the code to hyperlink, does font work? just trying to see if the combination of hyperlink and font is not working...

```
var myStyle = workbook.CreateCellStyle();
var myFont = workbook.CreateFont();

myStyle.BorderBottom = BorderStyle.Double;
myStyle.SetFont(myFont);
//cell.Hyperlink = new XSSFHyperlink(HyperlinkType.Url) { Address = url };
cell.CellStyle = myStyle;
```

Still outcome is the same

> Excel completed file-level validation and repair. Some parts of this workbook may have been repaired or rejected.
>   Records repaired: Font from parts /xl/styles.xml (Styles)

Comment: start with the basic and dont change the font or style, only set the hyperlink, slowly work up to find out which bit seems to cause the issue

Comment: if you remove the code to hyperlink, does font work? just trying to see if the combination of hyperlink and font is not working...

Comment: @KrishnaChaithanyaMuthyala Answer in post.

Comment: Am using npoi 2.0.1 with ASP.NET MVC and it works (font part, not sure of hyperlink)...may be it's a bug in the version you are using

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug in NPOI 2.4.1 and it will be fixed in the next release:

https://github.com/tonyqus/npoi/issues/165

For now just set FontHeight or FontHeightInPoints and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

After updating to the latest version NPOI.2.5.5, I was getting an error to open the an excel file and the message was "We found a problem with some content in abcd.xls. Do you want us to try to recover as much as we can? ...
Excel was able to open the file by repairing or removing the unreadable content
Repaired Records: Font from /xl/styles.xml part". due to deprecated code in the application, I was getting this error.

After updating the deprecated code to the latest code. it is started working and we are not getting any error to open the excel file.

Find the deprecated code and update it